# Recursive method Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion

I'm checking is first letter of string is 0, if it is remove it and call again method to check is there is still 0. I've debugged this and it seems like when it accomplish number without 0, it goes backwards. Code:

```
-(NSString *)deleteZerosOnFirst:(NSString *)card
{
    NSString *firstLetter = [card substringToIndex:1];
    if ([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        card = [card substringFromIndex:1];
        [self deleteZerosOnFirst:card];
        NSLog(@"CARD: %@", card);
        return card;
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"CARD: %@", card);
        return card;
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of using the for loop?  Why do you need to make it recursive?

Comment: Could you give me some hint how to do that? It should iterate until condition that 0 is not first character is satisfied.

Comment: You're not combining the results of the recursion anywhere. The result of the first call is always just the original argument minus a single initial `@"0"`. And what do you mean by "backwards"?

Comment: I've debugged this, and it goes something like this for example: 0007->007->07->7->07->007->0007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your recursive call:

```
    [self deleteZerosOnFirst:card];
```

That doesn't modify the string that `card` references. It creates and returns a new string. You're ignoring the returned string. You want this:

```
    card = [self deleteZerosOnFirst:card];
```

But this is really a lot simpler:

```
@implementation NSString (withoutLeadingZeroes)

- (NSString *)withoutLeadingZeroes {
    NSString *s = self;
    while ([s hasPrefix:@"0"]) {
        s = [s substringFromIndex:1];
    }
    return s;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hey Rob, does your simplified method have to be in a category, or can you add it to any .m file you like?

Comment: You could implement it as a method on any class, or as a free function, but it makes the most sense as a category.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you're not using the result of the recursion. The line of code where you call yourself should say this:

```
card = [self deleteZerosOnFirst:card];
```

Also, you're calling deleteZerosOnFirst before you do the NSLog. Reverse the order of these two lines. That will at least give you your debug output in the right sequence.